# Gold tag badge clarification

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges, tag-badges

It's not a big deal but I was just curious if someone could clarify how the gold tag badge works?

As example, I'm over 9k rep on SO and by far the majority of area of contribution is in the XAML tag category. The requirement to achieve gold is stated as

> Earn at least 1000 total score for at least 200 non-community wiki answers in the tag

The issue is, my "progress tracking" seems just stuck at 450/1000 which is odd considering probably 95% or more of my >9k rep is from the xaml tag. So I must be missing something since I would think I would have qualified a long time ago for it?

Like I said it's not a big deal or anything, I just thought it would be kind of neat to have the gold for that tag since there's only like 4 other people with it. So was just curious. Thanks!

Am I just misinterpreting and what it actually means is that at least 200 answers need to be 1k score or more each?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not a reputation thing in terms of points. To get a gold tag badge you need 1000 **up votes**, not 1000 points in that tag. [From Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work)

> A tag score is basically the combined total of all the upvotes (+1) and downvotes (-1) you've accumulated on answers under that specific tag (votes on questions do not count). As well, posts which are in community wiki status or that have been deleted do not count towards your tag score.

You can see this if you mouse over the tag score in your profile

[image]

Comment: Ah ok so it's not by the say 10+ upvote points or whatever but the act of the upvote itself that is added to your "score"? I think I got ya. Thanks

Comment: Note that there are three major differences between this and rep: 1/10th speed for upvotes, equal up/downvotes, and doesn't count accepts.  So if you received only upvotes, no accepts, and no downvotes, you would get the gold badge at 10k rep in a tag; but if you receive accepts for every answer, and had an average of 1.5 upvotes per answer, you'd need 20k rep (you'd get 10k rep in upvotes and 10k rep in accepts).

Comment: @Joe: Fourth difference: votes count for "score" even if they're rep capped, I believe.

Comment: @JonSkeet Good point, and certainly the person who'd know I suppose :)  And - I can actually confirm that, as I just had a major rep-cap answer on [money.se], and my score must reflect all of those votes, as I got the silver badge with one of the early upvotes for that question - and now am a bit over 100 score over the silver badge threshhold (roughly equal to the score from that question).